# FULLTEXT - Score by matching words 1st then by occurrences 2nd

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to find a way of ordering my MySQL FULLTEXT results in a certain order. Let's say I have these records:

```
ID  |   Title                              
----+-----------------------------------
1   |   Test test test truck from a test company.
2   |   Test car from Germany.
3   |   A car from London.
```

Now, if I ran the following query:

```
SELECT id, MATCH (title,keywords) AGAINST ('test car') AS score
FROM titles_tbl
WHERE MATCH (title,keywords) AGAINST ('test car')
ORDER BY score DESC
```

(Note: In my app I am using FULLTEXT across two columns, title and keywords. In this question, I am only querying one column as an example.)

It returns all records as it should but the order baffles me. I can understand what the score is and where it comes from but I want it in a different order. The above query would return results similar to this:

```
ID  |   Title                                            | Score
----+----------------------------------------------------+---------
1   |   Test test test truck from a test company.        | 1.5
2   |   Test car from Germany.                           | 1.0
3   |   A car from London.                               | 0.5
```

Where it found more occurrences of 'test' than anything else in row 1, it scored it heavier, even though 'car' wasn't found in that row at all. I would actually like it to score heavier where both words 'test' and 'car' and matched. So, in actual fact, row 2, "Test car from Germany" should actually be ranked higher as it contains both words and 2 and 3 should be ranked lower as they do not contain both words but then should be ordered by how many times they were mentioned.

So, in short, I want to order my results starting with all matching words and ending in one or more matching words, AND THEN order by how many times the words were actually mentioned.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I would like to see this answered too

Answer (score 1):

Try IN BOOLEAN MODE:

```
mysql> select id, title, MATCH(title) against ('test car' in boolean mode) m  
         from titles_tbl 
        order by MATCH(title) against ('test car' in boolean mode) desc\G 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 2
title: Test car from Germany
m: 2
*************************** 2. row ***************************
id: 1
title: Test test test truck from a test company.
m: 1
*************************** 3. row ***************************
id: 3
title: A car from London
m: 1
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.5.  Make sure you are running a recent version if IN BOOLEAN MODE does not properly score your searches.

Comment: Wonderful.. didn't think this would get answered. Give me a day or so to put together a test app and will get right back to you. Thanks.